# Stop excel form debugging

Tags: vba, debugging, excel

I made a custom function in VBA, and when I called it from a cell, some error occurred. I am not able to edit the cell or save the file because excel is "debugging". If I try to edit excel cells, it gives a "beep", and if I try to save, it shows this dialog. I have tried pressing the blue square (reset) button in VBA many times. How do I stop this "debugging"?

Following is how VBA code looks like. The problem arose because I created a function named x(), and triggered it by calling ri() from a cell. After reading comments, I now know that I can stop debugging by renaming the function temporarily, but what is the right way to stop excel from "debugging"? I have also kept "Auto Syntax Check" unticked.

[image]

Following is the error message which appears on trying to save document.

[image]

Comment: Try commenting out all the code, or even just change the function name so it stops getting called.

Comment: In VBA editor, I went File-> Close. Now I have excel tab in taskbar, but nothing shows up when I click on it. I am not able to close is either. What do I do?! Kill it using taskbar? Please help me!

Comment: Yes - kill it using Task Manager.

Comment: @TimWilliams, killed it, started again, recovered old excel file. Got same error on evaluating the cell, renaming the function temporarily worked indeed, it opened the excel editor for me. Thanks!!

Comment: Try posting the code that you're using so that we can try and see what is happening.

Comment: @SO, actually this happens often, I just wanted to know how to stop debugging, irrespective of the mistakes in my code :)

Comment: Does this code reside in an add-in or a normal workbook? Also - try pressing Ctrl + Break if the stop button isn't working.

Comment: @SO, I triggered the error once again, tried saving and got the same "can't save while debugging" appeared. Now, I pressed CTRL + [Pause|Break] Key. Nothing visible happened, pressed save, and got the same "can't save while debugging", thanks for helping though. I have posted my code to trigger this.